# Programming error "argument is of length zero" %in%

Tags: r

I get a continuous error in the first "%in%" statement. I have checked the other "argument of length zero" answers and didn't see any that applied.

Testing just `data$var[1] %in% Group1Zips` returns FALSE in the R console, so I must be missing something beyond a NULL value being returned.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    NewColumn= vector() 
    builder = function(data, TRXVAR, ZIPVAR){

    Group1 <- 0
    Group1Zips = vector()
    Group2 <- 0
    Group2Zips = vector()
    Group3 <- 0
    Group3Zips = vector()
    Group4 <- 0 
    Group4Zips = vector()
    Group5 <- 0 
    Group5Zips = vector()
    for (i in 1:nrow(data)){
    if (data$ZIPVAR[i] %in% Group1Zips){
    Group1 = Group1 + TRXVAR[i]
    append(NewColumn,"Group1")
    break }
      else if (data[i, ZIPVAR] %in% Group2Zips){
    Group2 = Group1 + data[i, TRXVAR]
    append(NewColumn, "Group2")
    break
  }
  else if (data[i, ZIPVAR] %in% Group3Zips){
    Group3 = Group3 + data[i, TRXVAR]
    append(NewColumn, "Group3")
    break
  }
  else if (data[i, ZIPVAR] %in% Group4Zips){
    Group4 = Group4 + data[i, TRXVAR]
    append(NewColumn, "Group4")
    break
  }
  else if (data[i, ZIPVAR] %in% Group5Zips){
    Group5 = Group5 + data[i, TRXVAR]
    append(NewColumn, "Group5")
    break
  }
  else if (Group1 < Group2){
    Group1 = Group1 + data[i, TRXVAR] 
    append(Group1Zips, data[i, ZIPVAR])
    append(NewColumn, "Group1")
    break
  }
  else if (Group2 < Group3){
    Group2 = Group2 + data[i, TRXVAR]
    append(Group2Zips, data[i, ZIPVAR])
    append(NewColumn, "Group2")
    break
    }
  else if (Group3 < Group4){
    Group3 = Group3 + data[i, TRXVAR]
    append(Group3Zips, data[i, ZIPVAR])
    append(NewColumn, "Group3")
    break
    }
  else if (Group4 < Group5){
    Group4 = Group4 + data[i, TRXVAR]
    append(Group4Zips, data[i, ZIPVAR])
    append(NewColumn, "Group4")
    break
    }
   else if (Group5 < Group1){
    Group5 = Group5 + data[i, TRXVAR]
    append(Group5Zips, data[i, ZIPVAR])
    append(NewColumn, "Group5")
    break
    }
  else {
    Group1 = Group1 + data[i, TRXVAR]
    append(Group1Zips, data[i, ZIPVAR])
    append(NewColumn, "Group1")
  }
 }
 return(nrow(NewColumn))
}
```

edit**

Here's a sample of the data:

```
    PROVIDER.ID ZIP TRX_ALL SPEC_CODE   
    2432188006  10013   4331    NEP 
    0050676082  90012   3050    IM  
    4954985007  77479   3043    CD  
    0250771087  90031   3020    OPH
```

Comment: It returned `FALSE`. It's doing its job then. `Group1Zips` is an empty vector.

Comment: Please make your example reproducible, we do not have your data.

Comment: That said, please post some data and clue us in on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Sorry about that: Each row represents a sales account. The data includes zipcodes in ZIP, and an integer amount for total scripts (I'm in pharma) in TRX_ALL. My purpose for this is to automatically split the accounts into five groups, with each group have about the scripts

Answer (score 1):

Your code is missing a "}" somewhere, and I don't think you give enough data to reproduce this, but it looks a lot like your if statement should be:

```
if(data[i, ZIPVAR] %in% Group1Zips){
```

The way you've written it will be looking for a column called "ZIPVAR" in any object you give it, instead of looking for a column named with the value of ZIPVAR.

Comment: Here's an example of what my dataframe looks like:

Comment: that format of data[i, columnName] looks like it helped pass that particular error. I still don't have it working, but will post here when I do. Thanks for the help.

Comment: So, the data[i, ZIPVAR], is telling it to look in row "i" and column "ZIPVAR" of the dataframe? Should I pass "dataframe$ZIPVAR as the variable or just "ZIPVAR"?

Comment: if `i <- 3` and `ZIPVAR <- "var"` then `data[i, ZIPVAR]` is equivalent to `data[3, "var"]` or `data$var[3]` so in that case, you should pass the name (or number) of the column to the function as ZIPVAR. You could re-write the if statement to accept dataframe$ZIPVAR style input though.

Comment: Got you -- that makes sense. Pretty confident now that that syntax is not the source of the error. Thanks again.

Comment: @ping, you might be missing a parenthesis yourself. How about `if ((`?

Comment: @r2evans Thanks for pointing that out! :) was actually an unnecessary ")" rather than a missing "("